# Getting gnuplot to work in JRuby - "RuntimeError: gnuplot executable not found on path"

Tags: jruby, gnuplot, runtime-error

I've installed gnuplot using...

```
jruby -S gem install gnuplot
```

But I get "RuntimeError: gnuplot executable not found on path" when I try to run it using...

```
require 'gnuplot'
```

If I change it so I say...

```
require 'C:\jruby-1.7.0.preview1\lib\ruby\gems\shared\gems\gnuplot-2.5.0\lib\gnuplot'
```

I still get the same error. Any advice? When I change the require command to reference the exe it gives a LoadError. So I'm assuming I should set up the path to the exe in some other way. I have installed gnuplot seperately.

Where/how do I setup the path correctly?

Comment: Did you install gnuplot separately?  I'm guessing you need to install gnuplot and put it somewhere on your PATH (I don't know how to do that on windows).  The jruby install probably just installs a gnuplot interface which farms out the real work via a pipe of some sort to gnuplot.

Comment: Hi yes I installed it. I'm not sure how to make it find the executable. If I change the require command to refer to the directory of the exe I get a load error. So I am assuming I should still just say require 'gnuplot' but set up the path to the exe some other way?

Answer (score 0):

Consult the intall logs or use "find" to find out where it's installed.

Comment: Please refrain from using footers to promote your book. That's frowned upon here. At least one of your answers was flagged as spam as a result. I'm going back and editing the others.